# Saving image on iOS 5.1.1 works randomly

Tags: iphone

I am trying to save an image taken from UIImagePickerController using the following code:

```
NSString *docsDirectory = 
  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) 
    objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.png"];

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

After saving the image i again read the image in another screen :

```
NSString *docsDirectory = 
  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) 
    objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.png"];
UIImage *extractedImage= [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];
```

This code runs fine on iPhone 4 (iOS 5.1.1), but on devices iPhone 4's (iOS 5.1.1), iPad 1 (iOS5.1) and iPad 2's (iOS5.1.1) this code works randomly.

Sometimes the is image is saved the very first time and sometimes it gets saved after trying 2-3 times.

Comment: Solved the issue, the issue was with the special characters in the image name i was using for saving.